# What's the easiest way I can include & link libraries with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, codeblocks

Is there anyway to simply just add search directories for the compiler and linker and add linker settings similar to what you'd do with code::blocks?

[code::blocks compiler search directory example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkktW.png)

[code::blocks linker search directory example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lRe5.png)

[code::blocks linker settings example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFsBY.png)

If code::blocks wasn't outdated and lacked things like decent code completion and linting, I wouldn't even use cmake. But this is apparently the best option if I want to use an editor like visual studio code or sublime text 3.

I just can't figure out how to simply do include_directories and link_libraries without cmake fussing at me.

Edit: here was my most recent attempt and the closes I've got it to working.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Platformer)

include_directories(
    libraries/raylib/include
)

set(
    RAYLIB
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/raylib/lib/libraylib.dll.a
)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(Platformer ${SOURCES})
link_libraries(${RAYLIB})
```

this just gives me a bunch of undefined references

[this is what my project structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxRfy.png)

Comment: It would be better if you could show us a [mcve] of a simple example project where you have problems, and include the `CMakeLists.txt` file as well as the errors or other messages you get when running the `cmake` command and building the program.

Comment: `target_link_libraries( ... )`

Comment: I'm sorry about that I included my most recent attempt and showed what my project structure looked like. I'm still new to stackoverflow I'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

The command `link_libraries` affects only on the executable/libraries **created after** the command call. This is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/link_libraries.html):

> Specify libraries or flags to use when linking any targets created **later** in the current directory or **below** by commands such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()`.

Your executable `Platformer` is created *before* the `link_libraries` call, so it is not linked actually.

You need either to swap calls to `add_executable` and `link_libraries`:

```
link_libraries(${RAYLIB})
add_executable(Platformer ${SOURCES})
```

or use `target_link_libraries` instead of `link_libraries`

```
add_executable(Platformer ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(Platformer ${RAYLIB})
```

(in the latter case the order is not reversed: `target_link_libraries` requires an already created target as the first argument).

---

Note, that `target_link_libraries` is generally preferred over `link_libraries` call as it produces the project in more structured manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have multiple executables that ALL use RAYLIB then move the link_libraries line up before the SOURCES i.e. after the definition of RAYLIB, because its effect is any executable defined afterwards. Otherwise use target_link_libraries for each target that needs it.

I'm really just echoing @Tsyvarev in different words, but I couldn't think of a way to state my thoughts as a comment.